# How to use FlatList without using state for data

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to use FlatList for large data, this data is paginated by server, and I fetch new Items using `onEndReached` function (to load more data when scrolling) and then add result to current data (stored in `state` variable) .

```
this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(res.data)})
```

but every time I use this method, FlatList renders all items (Full ReRender)
so I get error:

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
>   sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
>   performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
>   etc.

I'm using **PureComponent** for my list items, but its not the problem with rendering items (with log I noticed every component will render one time), **just FlatList makes a full render operation when state.data changes**.

please help me how to solve this problem
thanks

**Edit:**
renderItem function :

```
_renderSection(info) {
        if(info.item.isHeaderSection) {
            return (
                <ArtistBundleItem
                    style={styles.bundle}
                    bundle={info.item}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <ArtistItem3
                    title={info.item.name}
                    imageUrl={Constants.media.url(info.item.thumbnail)}
                    bgImageUrl={Constants.media.url(info.item.wallpaper)}
                    followers={info.item.followers}
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

and my flat list :

```
<FlatList
                style={UI.styles.screen}
                data={this.state.data}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
                renderItem={this._renderSection.bind(this)}


            />
```

Comment: Post your `renderItem()` implementation please.

Comment: edited... `ArtistItem3 -> PureComponent`, `ArtistBundleItem -> PureComponent`

Answer (score 0):

use the extraData prop of Flatlist. This will ensure that the FlatList will re-render only when new data is added to the state.

in your case:
extraData = {this.state.data}

additionally, I am not sure binding inside rendering is a good practice. In many optimization recommendations, they all say binding should be done in the constructor like below. This has improved performance for me quite a bit.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this._renderSection = this._renderSection.bind(this);
  }
```

and in your FlatList:

```
renderItem={this._renderSection}
```

Also, make sure that the key is unique and does not change when a re-rendering happens. looking at your code, I think you have it right.

Comment: not working, same result.
`VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 5504.5, "dt": 697, "prevDt": 622}`

I used `data={this.state.data}`, `extraData={this.state.data}` and binding methods in constructor.

Comment: also I'm setting new state like this (when loading new data from server(20 items)):
**`this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(res.data)});`**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you're storing the data in the state.

The problem is in the components that are being rendered by your `_renderSection` function.

As the warning says: `make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.`

So you have to check and change the components rendered by the `renderItem` function, which in your case are `ArtistBundleItem` and `ArtistItem3`.

Check out [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649#issuecomment-296987773) link to see how to do it.